# Image Experts for Android Camera

Tags: android, image, android-camera

Been trying to upload a high quality compressed image to S3 but it keeps on coming out pixaleted.

This is my hacked together code been at it a few days so would love some fresh eyes. Been trying to keep every picture exactly the save size and keep the aspect ratio the same.

But seems to impact the quality and resolution.

```
   private void saveImage(){
          if (isExternalStorageAvailable() && !isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
                pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                int num = Exif.getOrientation(data);
                if (num > 0) {
                    bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, num);
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleImage(bitmap);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
                    saveImageLocation(contentUri.getPath());
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not save your image!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Your phone doesn't have space for image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap image, int rotate) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "rotate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(rotate);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);

        return image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }

    private Bitmap scaleImage(Bitmap image) {
        int height = 600;
        double aspectRatio = (double) height / image.getHeight();
        int width = (int) (image.getWidth() * aspectRatio);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

    private void saveImageLocation(String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("image", value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(getAlbumStorageDir("companyname") + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_" + phoneid + ".jpg");
        return mediaFile;
    }

    private File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        File path = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File file = new File(path, albumName);
        file.mkdirs();
        return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to do the work of resizing and rotating the image

inside an `Async Task` doInBackground write the following line

```
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(file)//
                       .resize(100,100).centerInside().get();
```

Picasso auto rotates the image if the image's orientation is written in the exif data

`centerInside()` will make sure the aspect ratio remains correct

now you can send the image